# How to list a particular interval of a directory?

Tags: shell, unix, ls

I want a particular interval of a directory. For example:

directory:

```
one
two
three
four 
five
six 
seven
eight
nine 
ten
```

I want to list the directory between the three to nine only. Can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean.  Remember that there is no such thing as an ordering of files in a directory.  You can sort them lexicographically or however you want but you'll have to decide.  If your names are always “one” … “ten”, then of course you can hardcode said names.

Answer (score 0):

you could acheive that using combination of tail and head. may be something like this ...

```
$ ls|sort -n
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

$ ls|sort -n|tail -10|head -7
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```